# Download file is not working in latest version of google chrome [65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Below function was working fine in previous verion of chrome `64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)` , but same is not working in latest version of google chrome. `[65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)]` .Insteadof  downloading file, its opening in same tab.

Why this change in behaviour came in latest version of chrome and how we can achieve this ?

This is Function having javaScript lines to download file in same tab:

```
$scope.downloadFile = function (file) {
            var downloadLink = document.getElementById('downloadDocLink'); 
            downloadLink.target = '_self';
            downloadLink.href = file.serverPath;
            downloadLink.download = file.filename;
            downloadLink.click();

        }
```

HTML :

```
<a id="downloadDocLink" ng-hide="true"></a>
<button ng-click="downloadFile(file)">Download</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encountered same problem in my project. Download failures are now behave like navigation to different page rather than message in download bar. Since version 65, Chrome has different behavior for download. 
Google blocked cross-origin 
[Deprecations and removals in Chrome 65](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations)

Comment: Oh !!But how we can achieve this thing ?  any   different logics

Answer (score 1):

Here's how my download script that I wrote a while back, it works with the latest version of Chrome too, parameters to this function are; blob (blob object to download) and name (string for file name)

```
if (navigator.msSaveBlob)
    return navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, name);

var a = $("<a style='display: none;'/>");

var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.attr("href", url);
a.attr("download", name);
$("body").append(a);
a[0].click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
a.remove();
```